# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, kernel, finance

> I had this expression: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log   """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
>
> while trying this:

IN1:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

IN2:

```
tickers = ['BP', 'F', 'XOM', 'LNC', 'AAPL']

sec_data = pd.DataFrame()

for t in tickers:
    sec_data[t] = wb.DataReader(t, data_source='yahoo', start='2000-1-1')['Adj Close']
```

IN3:

```
sec_returns = np.log(sec_data / sec_data.shift(1))
sec_returns
```

OUT3:

```
                BP          F          XOM         LNC         AAPL
Date                    
2000-01-03     NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2000-01-04  -0.005328   -0.033984   -0.019340   -0.029223   -0.088078
2000-01-05  0.033616    0.003697    0.053082    -0.035209   0.014528
2000-01-06  0.002064    0.001230    0.050405    0.018136    -0.090514
2000-01-07  -0.018731   0.071119    -0.002939   0.025022    0.046281
... ... ... ... ... ...
2020-01-21  -0.011675   0.005444    -0.014397   -0.025472   -0.006800
2020-01-22  -0.011549   -0.005444   -0.005788   0.003241    0.003563
2020-01-23  0.008412    -0.002186   -0.006271   -0.006664   0.004804
2020-01-24  -0.001834   -0.015436   -0.006762   -0.030991   -0.002886
2020-01-27  -0.018262   -0.012297   -0.024112   -0.034176   -0.029846

5048 rows × 5 columns
```

**C:\Program Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.**

Is there any chance to avoid this RuntimeWarning?
Maybe it's because of negative values? But I need them.

P.S.- doing that on windows 10, jupyter-notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Log isn't defined for negative values, only for positive ones. You simply can't take the log of a negative value. That's not a python problem, it's a math problem.

Comment: The OP's code is a sample from an online course. I executed it yesterday without an error.  Today I get OP's error.  While your response is correct it doesn't reflect what the code is doing (or what data it's operating on).  The code operates on a numpy array of stock values, which are (or should be) all positive.  It calculates a return value by dividing a stock value by the previous day's and taking the log.  If today > yesterday, result > 1 and the log is positive.  If today < yesterday, 0 < result < 1 and the log is negative.  Those are the results you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

**Why does it work without any RuntimeWarning in this case?**

IN1:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
```

IN2:

```
MSFT = wb.DataReader('MSFT', data_source='yahoo', start='1995-1-1')
MSFT
```

IN3:

```
MSFT['log_return'] = np.log(MSFT['Adj Close'] / MSFT['Adj Close'].shift(1))
MSFT['log_return']
```

OUT3:

```
Date
1995-01-03         NaN
1995-01-04    0.007243
1995-01-05   -0.016632
1995-01-06    0.016632
1995-01-09   -0.006205
                ...   
2020-01-22   -0.004816
2020-01-23    0.006137
2020-01-24   -0.010128
2020-01-27   -0.016865
2020-01-28    0.019769
Name: log_return, Length: 6312, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly the problem is in the data returned by Yahoo.  Having had the exact same issue as you, I've tried the same code using (a) different tickers (which is effectively what you've done by indexing just the MSFT column) and (b) different date ranges and in both cases avoided the problem.  I've been unable so far to identify an example of the data problem but when I do I will post.

PS the course does mention early on that the returned data may not always be clean but so far they haven't talked about mitigating techniques!

EDIT: I take that back.  Over the date range 2007 to today, the log computation fails with ANY ticker list with more than two elements (as far as I can find).  Alternatively a longer ticker list with a shorter date range succeeds.  Suggests hitting some kind of limit but surely numpy and pandas are designed to work with bigger arrays than this?

EDIT 2: Having experimented with different ticker counts and date ranges, it seemed that the log() operation would issue the warning if the dataframe contained more than 8000-and-something cells.  To eliminate the specifics of the yahoo data source and the pandas_datareader library, I wrote this:

```
eles = 8192
cols = 2
arr = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1, eles+1).reshape((int(eles/cols), cols)))
print(arr.head())
logarr = np.log(arr / arr.shift(1))
#logarr = arr / arr.shift(1)
#logarr = np.log(arr)
#logarr = np.log(arr / arr.add(3))
print(logarr.head())
```

Irrespective of the shape of the array, the warning is issued if the number of elements is greater than 8192. The commented variants do not show this problem: it only affects (as far as I have found) the combination of numpy.log() and pandas.DataFrame.shift().

8192, of course, is a power of 2 (8192 = 2^13), so this suggests (to me) a bug or limit affecting the interaction between numpy and pandas.  Or am I missing something?

Of course it IS "just" a warning.  The returned DataFrame seems to be complete and usable.  You can suppress it with

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=RuntimeWarning)
import pandas as pd
```

although suppressing runtime warnings across the board would make me feel rather uncomfortable

EDIT 3: After all that, it turns out that the answer is to upgrade numpy and pandas to the latest version (pandas: 1.0.3 and numpy: 1.18.2 at 2020-04-04).  Doh.  There's an important lesson!